# Jogging and Meditation

Tags: jogging

I want to start both jogging and meditation since both these activities have huge benefits. I really want to make these two activities my habits. I read it somewhere that a person should focus on one thing at a time if he or she wants to make it a habit. So should I add jogging and meditation to my routine simultaneously or should I practice one thing for some time and then start doing the other one too?

Comment: It depends on you. How willing are you to stick to a routine? If you feel that you are disciplined and won't give up, you should by all means do both.

Comment: They are very different activities.  There's no reason why they should conflict, as long as you set aside the time for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I read it somewhere that a person should focus on one thing at a time if he or she wants to make it a habit"

After you get up in the morning, you take a shower and also brush your teeth. You eat breakfast and do other stuffs like brushing your hair and getting ready for work or school. No one tells you to do so. When you practice so many habitual things on daily basis, why nor running and meditation? I know this may not related to you, but some people have damaging habits like smoking and alcoholism and other stuffs at the same time, while some have habits like exercising, reading and eating healthy. Everyone is different and there's no single rule to practice things. If you consistently do both, there would arrive a time when they'd turn into habits. Keep the timings separate like mediation in morning and jogging in evening, or the other way. If you could combine them and jog to a park where you mediate and then jog back, that's even better. See what works for you the best and then start practicing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing this up for me! I really appreciate this :)